# Add required validation on country code drop down [ intl-tel-input jquery plugin ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, intl-tel-input

[intl-tel-input plugin link](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)

I am using this plugin and i want to add required validation on country code drop down but this plugin don't let me do it.

i tried it but failed.

First i add selected class on drop down click event

```
$(document).on('click', '.country', function () {
    $(".flag-dropdown").find('.selected-flag').addClass('selected');
});
```

then i checked if the div doesn't have selected class then add error class in input field container div

But it's not working

```
$("input[name='mobile']").keypress(function () {
    var isSelected = $('.flag-dropdown').find('.selected-flag').hasClass('selected');
    if (isSelected == false) {
        $('.has-feedback').removeClass('has-success');
        $('.has-feedback').addClass('has-error'); 
    }
});
```

I am using bootstrap validation also

```
      mobile: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {min: 8, message: " "},
                    notEmpty: {message: " "},
                    regexp: {regexp: /^\+?[\d-]+$/, message: " "}
                }
              }
```

Any help will be appreciated.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also used this plugin and stuck in same issue and solved by these steps

**1** : Add callback function to your bootstrap validation

```
          mobile: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {message: " "},
                        regexp: {regexp: /^\+?[\d ]+$/, message: " "},
                        callback: {
                            message: '',
                            callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                                if(!$('div.flag-dropdown').find('.country').hasClass('active')){
                                    return false;
                                }else{
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
```

**2** : Change you click event by this code

```
$(document).on('click', '.country', function () {
    var selectCode = $('ul.country-list').find('.active').attr('data-dial-code');
    if($.type(selectCode ) === "string") {
        $('#contact_mobile').val('+' + selectCode);
    }else{
        $('#contact_mobile').val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: how to make it selected? :)